# Use of OpenVINO on a computer with 2 physical cpus

Tags: windows, cpu, openvino

I have an issue with a computer that has 2 sockets and 2 physical cpus, each one with 48 cores. If I run my program as a standard user, only the cores of cpu0 are used, if I run as administrator, all cores of both cpus are used. This is on Windows Server 2022.

I've setup my core to use AUTO and CUMULATIVE_THROUGHPUT. Code is in C++.

Has it something to do with OpenVino or Windows? I couldn't find information on how to solve that.

Answer (score -1):

This is more related to your system/Windows config instead of OpenVINO.

As a workaround You can try to enable both CPU as below:

1. Press "Windows+R" to open a Run dialogue box. Type "msconfig" in the "Open" field and press "Enter." The System Configuration window opens.
2. Click the "Boot" tab, then click the "Advanced Options" button. The BOOT Advanced Options window opens.
3. Click the check box labeled "Number of processors" to place a check mark inside it.
4. Click the drop-down list below the "Number of processors" label, then select "2."
5. Click "OK" to close the BOOT Advanced Options window, then click "OK" again to close the System Configuration window.
6. Exit all applications, then restart the computer. After you restart the PC, you should notice that Windows boots and opens applications faster.

Comment: That doesn't do anything good, I can see 48 cpus here, but if I select that, I reboot with only one socket instead of 2, so that looks more like a limitation. By default Windows is using all available cpus and cores.
I'd think it's more a user/administrator difference somewhere, but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: I believe this is best clarified by Windows experts instead of OpenVINO as they would know in depth of your underlying issues. You can check & post to their community forum instead: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us